# Boxed equation with number

Tags: equations, amsmath, framed

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\boxed{K_{k+1}=P_ka_{k+1}^T(a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N)^{-1}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Now how can I number this equation?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just replace `center` environment with `equation`. I think it looks a little better with larger parentheses.

Edit: It might be easier to read as a fraction - except that it seems to be an equation about matrices ...

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{K_{k+1}=P_ka_{k+1}^T\left(a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N\right)^{-1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{K_{k+1}=\frac{P_ka_{k+1}^T}{a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 26):

With [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) help it's possible to include equation numbers in framed environments. It provides options `ams equation`, `ams gather`, `ams align` and corresponding starred versions. It's also possible to combine `tcolorbox` with `empheq` package.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!black, 
        highlight math style= {enhanced, %<-- needed for the ’remember’ options
            colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt}
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath{K_{k+1}=P_ka_{k+1}^T(a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N)^{-1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
K_{k+1}=P_ka_{k+1}^T(a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N)^{-1}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams gather]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x = \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{align*}
\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{f(x)}
&= \int\limits_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}~dt
= \left[ -\frac{1}{t} \right]_{1}^{x}\\
&= -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1}\\
&=
\tcbhighmath[remember,overlay={%
\draw[blue,very thick,->] (fx.south) to[bend right] ([yshift=2mm]frame.west);}]
{1-\frac{1}{x}.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How it can work for multiline long equations

Answer (score 14):

If you want a costumized box, you can use the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[
  amsmath
]{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0.45,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{cmyk}{0.25,0,0,0}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxM}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxT}
\newcommand*\Garybox[2][A Nice Box]{%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxT}{\fcolorbox{black}{light-blue}{#1}}%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \parbox[b][\ht\mysaveboxM+0.5\ht\mysaveboxT+0.5\dp\mysaveboxT][b]{%
      \wd\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
  }%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{shadecolor}{%
      \makebox[\linewidth-17.5em]{\usebox{\mysaveboxM}}%
    }%
  }%
  \usebox{\mysaveboxM}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\wd\mysaveboxM][c]{%
      \raisebox{\ht\mysaveboxM-0.5\ht\mysaveboxT
                +0.5\dp\mysaveboxT-0.5\fboxrule}{\usebox{\mysaveboxT}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box = {\Garybox[A Nice Box]}]{equation}
  K_{k+1}
  = P_{k}a_{k+1}^{T}\left(a_{k+1}P_{k}a_{k+1}^{T}+I_{N}\right)^{-1}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that my example is crudely stolen from [pages 23--24 of the package manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/empheq.pdf#page=23).

Answer (score 0):

The given answers are great and here is another solution using [`breqn`](https://ctan.org/pkg/breqn?lang=en):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
    \begin{dmath}[frame]
        K_{k+1}=P_ka_{k+1}^T(a_{k+1}P_ka_{k+1}^T+I_N)^{-1}
    \end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

You can also adjust the border thickness and spacing using:

`\begin{dmath}[frame={<amount>pt},framesep={<amount>pt}] ... \end{dmath}`

Comment: Note that `breqn` is highly experimental and probably shouldn't be used in production code.