# Box around one or multiple equations using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to put (1) a box around 1 equation inside an `align` environment, and also (2) a box around all equations in `align` environment. I'm already using `tcolorbox` and would like to use that. I have tried boxing all equations with `tcolorbox` but the problem is that it goes page-wide which I don't like, and also leaves a visible margin above the first equation. I want to keep equation numbers out of the box as well.
Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Thanks for pointing me to a solution. The problem, however, is that all the solutions use another math environment (either within `tcolorbox` or `empheq` package). I am using a very specialized align environment and hence have to have a box without `tcolorbox` or `empheq` equation style.

So I want a box around align equations without leaving `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` environment.

**Edit2:** Here is the MWE code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}

      \begin{gathered}

        A \quad  \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}} \\

        B \quad ~~ \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}}

      \end{gathered}

      &&

      \begin{aligned}\label{equationAB}

        A\: &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} a[n]\\

        B &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} b[n]

      \end{aligned}

      &&

    \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, show us your code. It is extremely unclear from your question what you have done and what you want to do. Any answer risk turning out to be useless.

Comment: Does this help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237855/1952 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240327/1952

Comment: The first link is really what I want, except that the box be around the actual equations and equations numbers be outside the box.

Comment: @QasimChaudhari: The `tcolorbox` solution with `tcbhighmath` should be what you request, in my point of view. Any `tcolorbox` can be configured to match top etc. spacing, background colour, frame style etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, how can I raise this question from dead after editing it? @ Ignasi, your solution helps but when using align equations, equation numbers are included. I want something like the first equation (number outside box) but with align environment. Thanks.

Comment: @QasimChaudhari: Returning after such a long time? ;-) I've voted to reopen it

Comment: @QasimChaudhari In second link, there's an `align` example with numbers outside box (equations 7 and 8).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Thanks :) @ Ignasi, Eq 7 and 8 use \begin and \end empheq, although I am using some particular settings with align, flalign, etc. and want to keep using actual align, flalign, etc.

Comment: @QasimChaudhari: We reopened your question, now provide a compilable document, not just requests ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I just added the MWE. I want a box around the equations such that A and B on the left and the number on the right are outside that box. Otherwise, A and B can be included if needed, but equation numbers must be outside.

Comment: Note that you can only ping one person per comment. So you can't ping both Christian and Ignasi at the same time. The system tells you this if you try.

Comment: @Ignasi: Any comments after this MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give a try with `tcolorbox`. Are you looking for the following?

[image]

The code puts a `\tcbhighmath` box around the aligned equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \begin{flalign}
    \begin{gathered}
      A \quad  \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}} \\
      B \quad ~~ \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}}
    \end{gathered}
    &&
    \tcbhighmath{\begin{aligned}\label{equationAB}
      A\: &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} a[n]\\
      B &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} b[n]
    \end{aligned}}
    &&
  \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ThomasSturm. For some strange reason, it is producing a yellow background in my office computer but when I compile at home computer, it has a pink background. How can I have it yellow consistently?

Comment: @QasimChaudhari There should be no difference. But you can change the coloring locally like `\tcbhighmath[colback=yellow]{...` or setting `highlight math style` globally (page 335 of the documentation v3.91).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Is it possible to set \tcbhighmath[<my options>] globally in (the preamble)? I would love for all my equation and align environments to be shaded automatically or by default?

Comment: @Raphael Yes, just adapt `highlight math style` or `highlight math` (page 373 of the documentation v4.51) for global effects, e.g. `\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={enhanced, drop shadow}}`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is not possible with `tcolorbox` because you should change the environment, but you can always use [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) or [`hf-tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) which can draw boxes around any part of your text.

Next code shows how to use `hf-tikz` commands `tikzmarkin` and `tikzmarkend`.
Both commands are defined like

```
\tikzmarkin{marker-id}(below right offset)(above left offset)
\tikzmarkend{marker-id}
```

`marker-id` is a label which is unique in every document and offsets are optional arguments to better adjust box size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
      \begin{gathered}
        A \quad \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}} \\
        B \quad ~~ \vphantom{\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1}}
      \end{gathered}
      &&
      \begin{aligned}\label{equationAB}
        \tikzmarkin{a}(1,-1)(-1,1) A\: &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} a[n]\\
        B &= \sum \limits _{n=0} ^{N-1} b[n]\tikzmarkend{a}
      \end{aligned}
      &&
    \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]