# Two-line boxed equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, box

I want to box the following two-line single equation. I checked the existing posts to no avail. Appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&hijoiojoij \\
&=iuiouooipip
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278799/box-around-one-or-multiple-equations-using-tcolorbox)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only the basic `\boxed` command, or `\fcolorbox` from `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\quad\begin{split}
&hijoiojoij \\
&=iuiouooipip
\end{split}\quad}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}
\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{Seashell}{\quad$ \begin{split}
&hijoiojoij \\
&=iuiouooipip
\end{split} $\quad}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hf-tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tikzmarkin{a}&hijoiojoij \\
&=iuiouooipip\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Every ornament needs a new label (in the example case `a`), but it wouldn't be very difficult to assign the label automatically.

[image]

The ornament style can be customized.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors,nofill,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

\hfsetbordercolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tikzmarkin{a}&hijoiojoij \\
&=iuiouooipip\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. It almost worked. Can the size of the box be customized? In my actual situation, the box doesn't fill up the whole equation.

Comment: @Fib1123 Look at the package documentation for fine tuning, there are several examples.