# How to highlight equations in mathematics?

Tags: highlighting

How I can highlight equation as given below:

[image]

Comment: Which part do you consider the highlight in the image?

Comment: [Like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237855/1952)

Comment: colored part of the above

Comment: @ Ignasi Like above

Comment: Like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413812/121799)?

Comment: How are you producing the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play around with the spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\suc}{Suc}

\begin{document}

By applying rule~2 (\texttt{apply\_rupple\_step}), the left hand side of the step-case is rippled to:
\[
  \colorbox{orange}{\strut
    case $b'$ of $0 \Rightarrow (\suc a) \mid (\suc z) \Rightarrow \suc(\colorbox{white}{$\max a \lfloor z \rfloor$})$%
  }
  {} = \max \lfloor b' \rfloor
  \colorbox{orange}{\strut
    $\suc \colorbox{white}{a}$%
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

Ultimately you can just use `\colorbox{<color>}{<stuff>}` to highlight content. I've added `\strut` to ensure a consistent baseline height of the resulting coloured box, as well as using text where it seemed necessary. Note that `<stuff>` inside a `\colorbox` is set in text mode.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the width and height of color spread?

Comment: I am using document class asmart in which text size is smaller

Comment: @new_born: You can replace the `\strut`s with `%`. That should shrink things vertically.

Comment: missing $ error is showing.   \[

 \colorbox{orange} { \strut (ht)^t = h^tg^tc }

\]

Comment: @new_born: As mentioned at the end of the answer, `<stuff>` inside `\colorbox` is set in text mode. If you want to use math - like your use of superscripts - you need to surround it with `$`s.