# How to insert a block in a formula

Tags: beamer

I am writing a presentation with Beamer and I would like to get the following effect: I have the formula

```
\begin{align}
a=b 
\end{align}
```

I would like (after that a=b appears) to put b inside a blue block and put an arrow that starts in the block and goes down and a zero after the arrow (just to say that b converegs to 0)

How should I do?

Comment: Can you please draw a sketch somehow of how it should look like in the end?? Can be handwritten + scanned or whatever ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A rude solution based on [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/boxed-equation-with-number/180326):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=blue!50!black, 
        highlight math style= {enhanced, %<-- needed for the ’remember’ options
            colframe=blue,colback=blue!10!white,boxsep=0pt}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
a=&\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{b}\\
\visible<2->{\\
&\tcbhighmath[remember, opacityback=0,enhanced jigsaw, boxrule=-0pt, no borderline, colframe=white, overlay={%
\draw[black,very thick,->] (fx.south) to ([yshift=0mm]frame.north);}]{0}
}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach using the `hf-tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[beamer,markings]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
a=\tikzmarkin<2>{a}b\tikzmarkend{a} 
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw<2>[->,red, thick] (a) ++(0.2,-0.4) -- ++(0,-1)  node[yshift=-8] {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]