# 2 boxes on each other with \columns

Tags: beamer, columns, tikzmark

I would like to display 2 boxes : one on each other beside a figure on a template. I am using the `\column` environment since it seems to be the most appropriate.
For the creation of the boxes, I am using `\tikzmarkin`. Also I would like to display an arrow that goes from the upper box to the lower one.

My coding gives this result :

[image]

Which is not exactly what I want, because the two boxes have not the same dimensions and there is no vertical spacing between boxes. Also, I tried to `\draw` an arrow between the 2 `\tikzmarkin` but it didn't work either...

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

%%%%%% ENCODAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

%%%%%% OTHERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{listings,stackengine}



\author{XXX}
\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\institute [XXX] {XXX \\ XXX}
\date{\today}


%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

%%%%%% BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\hfsetbordercolor{blue!50!black}

%%%%%% PGFPLOTS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
equal height group=C,
minimum for equal height group=C:1.5cm,
valign=center,
}}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
$\displaystyle\tikzmarkin<1->[set fill color=white, set border color=blue!50!black]{a}
\text{Plusieurs décades observées}
\tikzmarkend{a}
$
$\displaystyle\tikzmarkin<1->[set fill color=white, set border color=blue!50!black]{b}
\text{Confirmation de la loi d'échelle}
\tikzmarkend{b}
$  
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}
\phantomsubcaption
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[height= 0.55 \textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image} }}%
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is the most efficient way to do it please ? Thank you.

EDIT :

Why this alternative using `\tcolorbox` doesn't work either ?

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

%%%%%% ENCODAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

%%%%%% OTHERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{listings,stackengine}



\author{XXX}
\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\institute [XXX] {XXX \\ XXX}
\date{\today}

%\usepackage{YTU}

%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

%%%%%% VIDEO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multimedia}

%%%%%% BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\hfsetbordercolor{blue!50!black}

%%%%%% PGFPLOTS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
equal height group=C,
minimum for equal height group=C:1.5cm,
valign=center,
}}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \tcbhighmath[
         tcbox raise=0mm,
         remember as=a,
         colback=blue!10,
         colframe=blue
       ]{
    \text{Plusieurs décades observées}
    }
  \tcbhighmath[
         tcbox raise=0mm,
         remember as=b,
         colback=blue!10,
         colframe=blue,
         overlay={
          \draw[blue,-latex,thick] (a.south) -- (frame.north);
        }
       ]{
    \text{Confirmation de la loi d'échelle}
    }
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}
\phantomsubcaption
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[height= 0.55 \textheight,width=\linewidth]{pic/ComparaisonBerhanu.eps} }}%
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you again

Comment: Use tcolorbox with `remember as` just the same as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657268/linking-boxes-with-beamer or just an ordinary tikz picture

Comment: Ok : I will try. For the moment, I am still struggling to know which one to use \tikzmarkin or \tcolorbox

Comment: Don't use `\def`. You can get a better result with ``\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize\ttfamily\symbol{`\\}#1}}``

Answer (score 1):

Here a version with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

%%%%%% ENCODAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

%%%%%% OTHERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{listings,stackengine}



\author{XXX}
\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\institute [XXX] {XXX \\ XXX}
\date{\today}


%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

%%%%%% BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\hfsetbordercolor{blue!50!black}

%%%%%% PGFPLOTS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
equal height group=C,
minimum for equal height group=C:1.5cm,
valign=center,
}}


\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=blue,text width=.95\linewidth,align=center] (a) at (0,0) {Plusieurs décades observées};
\node[draw=blue,text width=.95\linewidth,align=center] (b) at (0,-3) {Confirmation de la loi d'échelle};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[height= 0.55 \textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image} }}%
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to make boxes to have same width too ? Also I have edited my original post in order to show you another attempt using \tcolorbox. Unfortunately, I am unable to draw an arrow between the 2 boxes : Could you tell me where am I wrong ? Thanks

Comment: You can set the text width to make them have the same with. As for the non-compilable code fragment you added to your question:  the `\draw` macro does not belong in the normal content of the box. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657273/36296 where the arrows are drawn

Comment: Thank you ! I was not writing it correctly so it was entirely my fault...